# Dynamics CRM 2011 Run Workflow / Process When Merging Contacts

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm, microsoft-dynamics

When Contact records are merged the Owner of the subordinate record loses a relationship to the master record and could lose the contact from Outlook, as syncing between CRM and Outlook is filtered on ownership or another connection to the underlying records.

When the records are merged, I would like to run a workflow / process (either before or after) that creates a connection between the 'losing' Owner and the Master record.

Comment: Fairly nice requirement you've written yourself there, good luck with it!

Comment: Do you want to **keep** the old, subordinate owner or do you want the **new**, master owner to keep a track of the previous one?

Comment: I'd like the subordinate owner to have a 'relationship' to the master post merging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When merging records the Master is stored in the Master ID field in the subordinate record so you can create a workflow that runs on Contact entity when the record status changes.

[image]

Add a check condition step to check if Master ID contains data and the Contact state is inactive (this will prevent the creation of connection when a record is only being deactivated)

[image]

[image]

Then add another step if the condition is met that creates a connection between the owner of the record and the Master Id

Comment: I can see MasterID in the entity fields but can't see it in the workflow field lists (or advanced find). Do I need to change something so that it shows up in the drop-down lists?

Comment: You need to select the Master ID in the Related Entities (see the main answer above, I've added a screenshot showing how to select it). This condition is just to check that there is a link between a Master and a subordinate which indicates the record has been merged